# PageFactory not working in VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, pageobjects

I am standing up a NUnit framework in VSCode but am running into an issue when setting up PageFactory within my page ctor. I have added DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects to my .csproj but am unable to call PageFactory.InitElements(driver,this) even with the using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects in place.

I have seen the articles/videos regarding PageObjects being removed from .Net Core but I thought (perhaps naively) that DotNetSeleniumExtras would solve this.

Has anyone gotten this working since PageObjects were pulled out into their own project?

Here are the steps I've followed in getting setup:

1) Install VSCode

2) Create New Folder

3) Open Folder in VSCode

4) Install .Net Core

5) Install Extensions:

> C#
>
> .Net Core Test Explorer
>
> Show Test Results (TDD Support for NUnit .Net Core)

6) Add NUnit Template:

> dotnet new -i NUnit3.DotNetNew.Template

7) Create a project:

> dotnet new nunit

8) Add Packages:

> dotnet add package Selenium.Webdriver
>
> dotnet add package Selenium.Support
>
> dotnet add package DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects
>
> dotnet add package NUnit
>
> dotnet add package NUnit3TestAdapter
>
> dotnet add package Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk

**.csproj Contents**

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Webdriver" Version="3.11.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Page.cs**

```html
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace IS.Pages
{
    class Landing
    {
        public Landing()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(DriverUtil.driver,this);
        }

        // Start Search Button
        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "body > main > header > div.background-wrapper > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > a")]
        public IWebElement AdvancedSearch {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, 
I didn't look at the Dependancies for DotNetSeleniumExtras. Not supported (yet) by .Net Core

[image]